# C2DM device not receiving message

Tags: php, message, registration, android-c2dm

I get the following response when I try to send a message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: text/plain 
Date: Sat, 31 Mar 2012 06:02:57 GMT 
Expires: Sat, 31 Mar 2012 06:02:57 
GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 
X-Content-Type-Options: 
nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; 
mode=block Server: GSE 
Connection: close 
Error=MissingRegistration
```

What can the issue be? Please help.

Comment: Hey were u able to resolve the issue?

Comment: yes there was an issue with the email i registered for C2dm